# How to add data in list view dynamically

Tags: android, json, listview, extends

I want to display data from webservice into `listview` dynamically and its work perfectly.

Now I want to extend `listview` when it goes to end (like facebook home page). How do I do this?

note: I am using json webervice to pass my data from php, and use list view to display parsed data in my app.

Here is my code:

```java
package info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.adater;

import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.R;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView; 

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;
    ProgressBar mSpinner;
    public static String s1="10";
    // Insert your Video URL
    String VideoURL;// = "http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/video/d2b6a230106f355d2eee796863f4088a.mp4";

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        convertView.setClickable(true);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);
        //TextView desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        videoview=(VideoView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        mSpinner=(ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
        VideoURL=m.getvideoUrl();
        videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(VideoURL));
        // videoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoview.requestFocus();
        // mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //pDialog.dismiss();
                mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                videoview.start();
            }
        });


        //videoview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(550,550));

        //    videoview.start();

        // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask


        //mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //play video

        // Start the MediaController

        //mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        //  Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        //videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        //  videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        //videoview.requestFocus(); 

        // Close the progress bar and play the video

        //videoview.start();

        // getting movie data for the row

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        // rating
        rating.setText(m.getDate());

        //desc.setText(m.getdesc());
        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear())); 

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean - [Pull to Refresh](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView)?

Comment: No i think you mean infinite scroll ?

Comment: yes when i goto last list of list its automatically load next 5post

Comment: i dont know how to say it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach :

I catch the `onScroll` of the `ListView` and load more item if it's needed. 
In my case i load more if i scroll to the half of the product seen

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if ((task == null || task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) && productHolder.hasProductRemainsToBeLoad() &&
            productHolder.getProducts().size() - (Config.PRODUCT_NUMBER_PER_PAGE/2) < firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount){
        loadProduct();
    }
}
```

Here task is an `Asynctask` who call a webservice. 
Then notify your adapter

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: can i explain it more please

Comment: 1 : catch the scroll of your listview : findViewById(R.id.listViewProduct).setOnScrollListener(this); 2 : Call your webservice if needed into the onScroll 3 : add your data to the list use in your adapter. 4 : notify your adapter that the data was changed

Comment: and when my app load it start to play all videos but i want to play one video that now shown on the screen

Comment: The trick is on the activity, fragment or view not in the Adapter. PS : If you have more question please fill free to an ask other question (about video player).

Answer (score 0):

Listviews have a listener used to check the position of the scroll. The following code will help you to check if you are at the end of your `ListView`.

First make your `Activity` of `Fragment` implements `OnScrollListener`. Then add

```
private int preLast;
// Initialization stuff.
yourListView.setOnScrollListener(this);



@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView lw, final int firstVisibleItem,
             final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {

switch(lw.getId()) {
    case R.id.yourIDListview:     

       final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
       if(lastItem == totalItemCount) {
          if(preLast!=lastItem){ //to avoid multiple calls for last item
            //LOAD MORE ITEMS
            preLast = lastItem;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using OnScrollListener.

```
 listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){

             @Override
             public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,int totalItemCount) {
                //Algorithm to check if the last item is visible or not
                final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                if(lastItem == totalItemCount){                 
                    // you have reached end of list, load more data  
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have reached last item!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Sent_details.clear();
                    //In here give a call to database and take another 5 posts and notify the listview
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
             }

             @Override
             public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,int scrollState) {
                //blank, not using this
             }
            });
```

Comment: thank you and is there any idea to found which list is shown on the screen

Comment: I'm not sure, Let's say you have 2 listviews on same activity, Create one object for both and before showing one listview, assign that id to the created object, using this you can use one object instead of two and u can easily find the current listview

Comment: or if we have able to store current list id to any local variable

Comment: Yes you can do it in that way also.. When you are updating the listview, put a if condition and check what listview is currently showing.